# How to customize the database value in magento customer grid

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I created new magento grid for customer module for special purpose.

In that there have a column `usertype` it have value as 0,1,2.

It will displayed in customer grid page as 0,1,2.

But i need to display if value is,

```
 0 -> Inactive
 1 -> Activated
 2 -> Baned
```

How can i dothis?

This is my code grid.php in _prepareColumns() :

```
$this->addColumn('usertype', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Usertype'),
            'width'     => '150',
            'index'     => 'usertype'
        ));
```

If this is possible in magento.

Comment: Any one have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution from [this](http://tipsmagento.blogspot.in/2011/03/add-new-column-on-customers-grid.html)

By using rendere will help to load vlaues to each row.

Comment: This points you in the right direction but it's really an answer. You should at least synthesize the important steps here.

Answer (score 1):

if your greed implements `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` I suggest you to modify
you `addColumn` call to

```
$this->addColumn('usertype',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('customer')->__('Usertype'),
            'width' => '150px',
            'index' => 'usertype',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'options' => $values
        ));
```

Where `$values` should be formatted as

```
array( 'value_id' => 'value_label')
```

Now you have dropdown created with values.
Then update `_prepareCollection()` function and add attribute values to customer grid collection
`$collection->joinAttribute('usertype', 'customer/usertype', 'entity_id', null, 'left');`